# Can I run custom code with AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-dynamodb

I've been experimenting with Google App Engine for the past few months. It's really easy to use, but it's just so limited what you can do. Namely, I can't use WebSockets or send Apple Push Notifications. Is DynamoDB the same way, that is I can't run "custom" code with it? Will I be able to use WebSockets or say run an XMPP server on it? I'm not entirely sure how that works with DynamoDB.

Comment: DynamoDB is just a service that allows you to store data.  It's probably more simple than App Engine.  Did you mean AWS RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, DynamoDB is only a (lean) database engine. It will store your data but won't run anything beside queries. If you need a general purpose server, you can have a look at EC2.

Answer (score 1):

App Engine does have an XMPP service: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/xmpp/ and https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview

Not that this'll help with Web Sockets or Apple Push Notifications.

The Channel API can be used provide persistent client connections: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS Lambda (Custom code) in conjunction with DynamoDB.